Excel Pivot Table Calculation
I want to make some calculations on my pivot table.
In the pivot table side, I have year-by-year sales income and amount for each product.
I want to see the differences between products year by year. For example, in 2024 I sold 1000 amount apples, previous year (2023) I sold 500 amount of apples. What I want to see the pivot table 500/1000= 0,5
How it would be possible to do?

Would double check your math if you want to see a % difference it wouldn't be 500/1000, it would be 1000/500 to show a 100% growth from 2023. To achieve this you would select the your values and "Value Field Settings", under "Show Values as" you'd want "% Difference From" and the base field as year and base item as (Previous); however, this won't match the .5, as this simply isn't how the calculation of % difference is calculated. To calculate you it your way it needs to be a calculated field.

If you do the % Difference from the Next it'd be close to what you're looking for the negative value of -50%.
